# Generate thumbnail for arbitrary audio file

Tags: python, audio, visualization

I want to represent an audio file in an image with a maximum size of 180×180 pixels.

I want to generate this image so that it somehow gives a representation of the audio file, think of it like SoundCloud's *waveform (amplitude graph)*?.

[image: Screenshot of Soundcloud's player]

I wonder if any of you have something for this. I have been searching around for a bit, mainly "audio visualization" and "audio thumbnailing", but I have not found anything useful.

I first [posted this to ux.stackexchange.com](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/17037/7206), this is my attempt to reach any programmers working on this.

Comment: Do you want to make a tool to do this or do you want a pre-existing solution?

Comment: That's not a spectrogram, it's an amplitude graph. Spectrograms of audio are three-d: usually time on the x-axis, frequency on y, and amplitude represented by color.

Comment: Thank you Josh Caswell, as you see, I was unsure about the name of this representation of a waveform.

Comment: @Koof - It does not matter, any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. Thought that clarification would probably help your search.

Comment: Take a look at this blog post about [wav2png.py](http://blog.freesound.org/?p=10).

Comment: Relevant blog post: http://blog.freesound.org/?p=10

Answer (score 3):

You could also break up the audio into a chunks and measure the RMS (a measure of loudness). let's say you want an image that is 180 pixels wide.

I'll use [pydub](http://pydub.com), a light-weight wrapper I wrote around the std lib `wave` modeule:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

# first I'll open the audio file
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("some_song.mp3")

# break the sound 180 even chunks (or however
# many pixels wide the image should be)
chunk_length = len(sound) / 180

loudness_of_chunks = []
for i in range(180):
    start = i * chunk_length
    end = chunk_start + chunk_length

    chunk = sound[start:end]
    loudness_of_chunks.append(chunk.rms)
```

the for loop can be represented as the following list comprehension, I just wanted it to be clear:

```
loudness_of_chunks = [
    sound[ i*chunk_length : (i+1)*chunk_length ].rms
    for i in range(180)]
```

Now the only think left to do is scale the RMS down to a 0 - 180 scale (since you want the image to be 180px tall)

```
max_rms = max(loudness_of_chunks)

scaled_loudness = [ (loudness / max_rms) * 180 for loudness in loudness_of_chunks]
```

I'll leave the drawing of the actual pixels to you, I'm not very experienced with PIL or ImageMagik :/

Comment: Convert `max_rms` to a float first. It helps.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Jiaaro's answer (thanks for writing pydub!), and built for web2py here's my two cents:

```
def generate_waveform():
    img_width = 1170
    img_height = 140
    line_color = 180
    filename = os.path.join(request.folder,'static','sounds','adg3.mp3')


    # first I'll open the audio file
    sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3(filename)

    # break the sound 180 even chunks (or however
    # many pixels wide the image should be)
    chunk_length = len(sound) / img_width

    loudness_of_chunks = [
        sound[ i*chunk_length : (i+1)*chunk_length ].rms
        for i in range(img_width)
    ]
    max_rms = float(max(loudness_of_chunks))
    scaled_loudness = [ round(loudness * img_height/ max_rms)  for loudness in loudness_of_chunks]

    # now convert the scaled_loudness to an image
    im = Image.new('L',(img_width, img_height),color=255)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    for x,rms in enumerate(scaled_loudness):
        y0 = img_height - rms
        y1 = img_height
        draw.line((x,y0,x,y1), fill=line_color, width=1)
    buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
    del draw
    im = im.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH).filter(ImageFilter.DETAIL)
    im.save(buffer,'PNG')
    buffer.seek(0)
    return response.stream(buffer, filename=filename+'.png')
```