# PIL/Pillow inverting transparency seemingly arbitrarily

Tags: python, gif, python-imaging-library, pydub

I have Pillow 2.4.0 installed (both in a virtual env on OS X and on a Ubuntu 14.04 EC2). I wrote the following script to generate a visualization of a waveform ([drawing some inspiration from Jiaaro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200252/generate-thumbnail-for-arbitrary-audio-file)). It uses the Pydub library to analyze the waveform and the ImageDraw function from PIL/Pillow to draw the lines. The wav variable is an audiosegment() (from the Pydub library), imgname is a string:

```
def draw_waveform(wav, imgname, color="#000000", w=400, h=40):
    sound = wav
    name = imgname
    width = w
    height = h
    color = color

    chunk_length = len(sound) / width

    loudness_of_chunks = [
        sound[ i*chunk_length : (i+1)*chunk_length ].rms
        for i in range(width)]

    max_rms = max(loudness_of_chunks)
    scale = max_rms/(height/2)

    size = (width,height)
    im = Image.new('RGBA', size, (255, 255, 255, 255))

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

    for i in range(1, width):
        pos = (width - i, height/2 + loudness_of_chunks[i]/scale-4)
        draw.line((width - i,height/2) + pos, fill=color)
        pos = (width - i, height/2 - loudness_of_chunks[i]/scale+4)
        draw.line((width - i,height/2) + pos, fill=color)

    del draw

    im.rotate(180).save(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + '/' + name, 'GIF', transparency=0) #, transparency=0

    return app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + '/' + name
```

All's groovy, most of the time. On some waveforms, particularly, it seems, the ones that are closest to peaking, PIL will output a GIF that has flipped transparency - the waveform will be transparent and the space around it will be white. Normally the background's transparent and the waveform is black (#000000).

Here is a picture of the expected output:

[image: Correct output]

And the incorrect (right click save-as and open in an image editor, as its background is white and the middle is transparent):

[image: Incorrect output]

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? Am I missing something obvious (likely)?

Comment: Try using image format `'P'` instead of `'RGBA'`, and setting the transparent index on the `save`. See http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#gif

Comment: Easy hack: you could create a completely black layer and overlay your current output over it. That doesn't solve your real question though, which I don't know the answer to ;)

Comment: @Jiaaro - unfortunately I need the transparency for the table I'm displaying them in. Incidentally, thank you ever so much for your excellent library (and I'll send you many a present if you add 24 bit support ;) )

Comment: @MarkRansom - I tried that and several variations. I managed to get a white image with a transparent background by setting color=255 and instantiating the image with im = Image.new('P', size, 0). Unfortunately the reverse does not produce the intended result, but rather the same incorrect rendering as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is simpler than I imagined it to be (surprise surprise). Thanks to @MarkRansom for inspiration here.

Instantiate the image with 'P' rather than 'RGBA',

```
im = Image.new('P', size, 255)
```

Define your color (for black, 0)

```
color=0
```

Ensure that the save call defines the *white* area as transparent rather than the black:

```
im.save(name, 'GIF', transparency=255)
```

Still a little curious why it would only fail some of the time with the original code...

Comment: Finally saw your answer 2 1/2 years after you wrote it. The reason it only failed some of the time is that the palette is adaptive, built from scratch based on the colors of your image. It's almost completely random which color will end up at index 0.